# Do we need the conditionals tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Lately there have been many suggested edits to add a new conditionals tag. I've been accepting these because strictly speaking they're correct.

However, do we need that tag? It seems that logic is enough; we don't need to specify further. What do we do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, we gain absolutely nothing by adding a separate tag for conditionals.

Comment: I have created a [synonym suggestion](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tags/logic/synonyms) for logic, but perhaps you can make this go quicker :)

Comment: it is done ....